# Where is merkle path of a transaction stored in a transaction?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

I understand every transaction can be verified if it belongs to a block by a merkle path which is basically a set of hashes that finally end up at the merkle root.

I know the merkle root is stored in the block header, but where is the merkle path (set of merkle hashes) of a transaction stored within the block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The merkle path is not stored explicitly within the block. It is calculated from the transactions in the block when requested by a client.